# java.awt.color.CMMException: LCMS error 12288

Tags: java, javax.imageio

ImageIO.read works for most of my images but throwing this exception for a particular jpg image.

```
im = ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("plan3v2.jpg"));
```

this line throwing exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.awt.color.CMMException: LCMS error 12288
        at sun.java2d.cmm.lcms.LCMS.getProfileData(Native Method)
        at java.awt.color.ICC_Profile.getData(ICC_Profile.java:1310)
        at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.setImageData(JPEGImageReader.java:652)
        at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.readImageHeader(Native Method)
        at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.readNativeHeader(JPEGImageReader.java:593)
        at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.checkTablesOnly(JPEGImageReader.java:338)
        at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.gotoImage(JPEGImageReader.java:470)
        at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.readHeader(JPEGImageReader.java:586)
        at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.readInternal(JPEGImageReader.java:1004)
        at com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEGImageReader.read(JPEGImageReader.java:984)
        at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1438)
        at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1342)
        at TestClass.run(TestClass.java:13)
        at TestClass.main(TestClass.java:8)
```

Not sure what the error "LCMS error 12288" mean.

Is there any alternative api that can read such images?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "LCMS error" exception message you see, originates from the LittleCMS color management module, that was introduced first in OpenJDK, but has now replaced KCMS (the original Kodak CMM used by Sun in their Java implementations) in Oracle JDK8.

Assuming the image is the same as referred to from [this RedHat bug report](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=695246) (it has the same file name, and causes the same exception), the [TwelveMonkeys ImageIO JPEGImageReader plugin](https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys#jpeg) can read it*.

The embedded ICC profile in the image is corrupt, so it is simply ignored by my reader, but the image is fully readable and looks okay still.

To use the plugin, you only need to place the plugin with dependencies on class path ([see example](https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys#maven-dependency-example)). Your existing code should then just work as before (without the exception that is). No need to change or recompile anything.

---

*) I've only tested on JDK 1.6 and OpenJDK 7 on OS X and JDK 7 and 8 on Windows, but it shouldn't matter. :-)

Comment: Well that works in my testcases. But when I deployed my web application in tomcat, getting same LCMS error again. I have verified that JAVA HOME is same in tomcat configuration. Please advise.

Comment: @JitendraChandani If the exception occurs, most likely you haven't installed the plugins correctly, or ImageIO isn't picking them up. Have you read [Deploying the plugins in a web app](https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys#deploying-the-plugins-in-a-web-app) and configured your `web.xml` accordingly? You can also use the code from [Installing](https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys#installing) in a `Servlet` to verify proper installation.

Answer (score 0):

What version of jre are you using? It appears this is fixed in 1.7.60.

http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6839133

https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6839133

Comment: Hi Brett, I am on OpenJDK version "1.6.0_17". Moving to 1.7 is not easier for me at the moment. Application is big enough and have lots of jar dependencies. Thanks.